# Where can I find all the subprocess.call() codes (0,1,2 ..)?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am running the following Python code and checked the docs of subprocess but still din't find the code map:

```
import pkg_resources
from subprocess import call

packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pkg_resources.working_set]
call("sudo pip3 install --upgrade " + ' '.join(packages), shell=True)
```

Output: 2

What 2 means? Sometimes it's 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Linux command executed by the shell script or user, has an exit status.

The Linux man pages stats the exit statuses of each command.

- 0 exit status means the command was successful without any errors.
- A non-zero (1-255 values) exit status means command was failure.

Typical signals are:

> 0 – Success.
>
> 1 – A built-in command failure.
>
> 2 – A syntax error has occurred.
>
> 3 – Signal received that is not trapped.

Certain exit status values have been reserved for special uses:

> 126 - A file to be executed was found, but it was not an executable utility.
>
> 127 - A utility to be executed was not found.
>
> 128 - A command was interrupted by a signal.

A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

The codes are platform specific, for example on Windows:

> 0 - Success
>
> 1 - Invalid function
>
> 2 - File not found
>
> 3 - Path not found
>
> 4 - Too many open files
>
> [etc...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

From the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> *Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to
> specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix
> programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all
> other kind of errors.*